# Converting two lists to json

Tags: javascript, json

I'm attempting to convert two lists to json.

For example :

```
l1 = ['a','b','a']
l2 = ['q','r','s']
```

should be converted to :

```
[{
    "name": "g",
    "children": [{
            "name": "a",
            "children": [{
                "name": "q"
            }, {
                "name": "s"
            }]
        },
        {
            "name": "b",
            "children": [{
                "name": "r"
            }]
        }
    ]
}]
```

Closest I have is :

```
l1 = ['a','b','a']
l2 = ['q','r','s']

nameDict = {}
childrenDict = {}

l1 = l1.map(x => {
  return({name: x});
});
console.log(l1);

l2 = l2.map(x => {
  return({children: x});
});
console.log(l2);

var c = l1.map(function(e, i) {
  return [e, l2[i]];
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(c))
```

which produces :

```
[[{"name":"a"},{"children":"q"}],
[{"name":"b"},{"children":"r"}],
[{"name":"a"},{"children":"s"}]]
```

How to combine the elements produce ? :

```
[{
    "name": "g",
    "children": [{
            "name": "a",
            "children": [{
                "name": "q"
            }, {
                "name": "s"
            }]
        },
        {
            "name": "b",
            "children": [{
                "name": "r"
            }]
        }
    ]
}]
```

Comment: Where does `"g"` come from?

Comment: If both arrays have the same length, do everything in one `array.map()`. Another option is to use a good ol' `for()` loop in order to check if there is actually an element with that particular index. Finally I assume that there is a relation between the elements (reason why one parent can have more than one children), you can always run that logic inside any method you end up using `map()` or `for()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: Since we don't know where the `g` comes from, I will only build the root `children` array.

Since your arrays have the same length, you can use a plain `for` and use with the index to play with both arrays. Just build an array and check each iteration if the "child" already exists. If not, create it.

```js
l1 = ['a','b','a']
l2 = ['q','r','s']

let gChildren = []
for(let i = 0; i < l1.length; i++){
  let group = gChildren.find(c => c.name === l1[i])
  if(!group){
    group = { name: l1[i], children: [] }
    gChildren.push(group)
  }
  
  group.children.push({ name: l2[i] })
}

console.log(gChildren)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is working code that accounts for your pre-existing structure that accomplishes the result you are looking for.

```
let data1 = ["a","b","a"];
let data2 = ["q","r","s"];

let outputData = [{name: "g", children: []}];

for (let i=0;i < data1.length;i++) {
        let found = false;
    for (let j=0;j < outputData[0].children.length;j++) {
        if (outputData[0].children[j].name === data1[i]) {
            outputData[0].children[j].children.push({name: data2[i]});
        found = true;
        }
      }
      if (found === false) {
            outputData[0].children.push({name: data1[i], children: [{name: data2[i]}]});
        }

}

console.log(JSON.stringify(outputData));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use case for a [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), where you want to iterate over an array but end up with a single value.

```
l1.reduce((acc, val, i) => {
  const l2Val = l2[i]
  const foundObj = acc.find(o => o.name === val)
  if (foundObj) {
    foundObj.children.push({name: l2Val})
  } else {
    acc.push({
      name: val,
      children: [{name: l2Val}]
    })
  }

  return acc
}, [])
```

Here, on each iteration I'm just adding the child to the children array for that item, or creating the value for the item if it doesn't already exist.

I have no idea what `g` corresponds to so I've left it out, but you can add the array created from `reduce` to another object or array if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could transpose the array and use the information as path to the final child object

```
l1 = ['a', 'b', 'a']
l2 = ['q', 'r', 's']
```

transposes to

```
[
    ['a', 'q'], // a -> q
    ['b', 'r'], // b -> r
    ['a', 's']  // a -> s
]
```

which is now works with reduce.

The advantage is to use it with longer pathes to the final children, like

```
[
    ['a', 'x', 'y', 'z'],
    ...
]
```

which returns a nested object with the given relation to each other.

```js
const
    transpose = array => array.reduce((r, a) => a.map((v, i) => [...(r[i] || []), v]), []);

var l1 = ['a', 'b', 'a'],
    l2 = ['q', 'r', 's'],
    result = transpose([l1, l2]).reduce((r, a) => {
        a.reduce((q, name) => {
            var temp = (q.children = q.children || []).find(o => o.name === name);
            if (!temp) q.children.push(temp = { name });
            return temp
        }, r);
        return r;
    }, { name: 'g' });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit shorter with filter on the distinct keys :

```js
var l1 = ['a','b','a'], l2 = ['q','r','s']

var children = [...new Set(l1)].map(k => ({ name: k, children: 
        l2.filter((v, i) => l1[i] == k).map(v => ({ name: v })) }))

console.log( [{ name: 'g', children }] )
```

Or more efficient with intermediate object of the groups :

```js
var l1 = ['a','b','a'], l2 = ['q','r','s']

var children = Object.entries(
                       l1.reduce((o, k, i) => ((o[k] = o[k] || []).push(l2[i]), o), {})
                     ).map(([k, v]) => ({ name: k, children: v.map(v => ({ name: v})) }))

console.log( [{ name: 'g', children }] )
```